# Are there any hidden layers in the following model, or just Input and output layers?

Tags: tensorflow

Are there any hidden layers in the following model, or just Input and output layers?

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', input_dim=1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `Dense` layer is the hidden layer. Keras internally assigns an input layer for the model, with 1 input unit (the parameter of `input_dim`)

Answer (score 0):

there is one hidden dense layer with `1024` neuron and `relu` activation function.

can plot model with:

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

[image]