# Hidden Layer in a Neural Network

Tags: python, deep-learning

So I'm currently completing my Udacity Nanodegree and there is this one point that i'm not able to understand.
In the input layer we're taking 784 because the pixel of MNIST dataset is 28x28, but i don't understand why are they taking 256 hidden layer. Where did this 256 number came from?

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62300357/are-there-any-hidden-layers-in-the-following-model-or-just-input-and-output-lay/62300480#62300480

Answer (score 0):

The 256 hidden layer represent the 0 to 255 value given to each pixel to represent saturation of color for that pixel.

Comment: I am interested. Is there any source for this? 
For me, it doesn´t seem to make any sense, since the saturation is represented by the value of the inputs. 

Usually one takes values of the set 2^n for n >= 0 to be memory efficient.

Comment: They do, colors are a 3x1 tuple. Each element is 2^7 number that represents either a red, green, or blue. 000 = Black, #fff = white. For a photo going into a neural network, the photo is looked at as 3 individual arrays, red green blue, that represent the image in a 28x28 shaped array.

Answer (score 0):

The number of units in hidden layers is an hyperparameter of the network, so just like any other hyperparameter (like the learning rate, regularization factor and so on) it is initially chosen arbitrarily, then its value is "tuned" by assessing the model's performances on the validation set.

Sometimes though, especially in small and contrived examples like MNIST, some hyperparameters are fixed once and for all and never tuned, given how simple the task at hand is. So yeah, chances are that the number 256 was chosen arbitrarily.